# Is the reputation system the same across all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, reputation

As the title says, I'm wondering if some sites have customised their pointing system.

I've just come across Troy Hunt's profile on Information Security: https://security.stackexchange.com/users/136/troy-hunt

Currently he has 2,785 points. But he also an answer that has 381 upvotes. He has other highly upvoted answers but this answer alone should give him 3,810 points assuming upvoted answer gets 10 points. I couldn't make sense of the numbers so decided to ask here.

Sorry if it's a silly question :-)

Comment: There’s still reputation caps that he hit [several times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tadb6.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [timeline for that answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/180589/timeline) he got 124 votes on the first day, followed by 73, 30, 30. So in those four days he would have hit the reputation cap of 200 and had a reputation increase of 800 rather than the 2570 otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of the daily caps.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the reputation system same across all Stack Exchange sites?

No, it's customizable, but it's the same on almost all sites, including Information Security. @PeterJ explains what happened here in [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322488/152859).

The only exception that I know of is [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com); it has a [customized reputation system](https://stackapps.com/help/whats-reputation) where an upvote to a question gives **+10 reputation** instead of +5.

Comment: Thank you. I realised I didn't do a great job with my question as the title asked something while I was interested in something else. Thanks for explaining the pointing system. That's been helpful.